# Video not playing from Uri link in VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have been trying to play a video inside VideoView which seems to be working fine in case when video is kept in res/raw folder but when using url of a video to fetch and play video, it doesn't seem to work.
I have given the internet permission in manifest file:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Using the code below:

```
    val tv:TextView=findViewById(R.id.tv)
    val vv:VideoView=findViewById(R.id.vidView)
    var uri= Uri.parse("http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4")
    //local resource playing
    //var localUri=Uri.parse("android.resource://$packageName/${R.raw.blood_video}")
    var mc=MediaController(this)
    vv.setMediaController(mc)
    vv.setVideoURI(uri)
    vv.requestFocus()
    vv.setOnPreparedListener {
        vv.start()
    }
```

I am not setting

> mc.setAnchorView(vv)

as i don't see a difference with it(at least at such a simple level i am working on)

Logcat:

```
2022-07-05 14:46:06.222 18430-18430/com.example.videoapp W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open http://techslides.com/...
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1673)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1503)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1420)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.attemptDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1104)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1076)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1100)
    at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:412)
    at android.widget.VideoView.access$2200(VideoView.java:83)
    at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:694)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface(SurfaceView.java:802)
    at android.view.SurfaceView$2.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:171)
    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:1088)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2930)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1811)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7970)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:967)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:791)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:726)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:952)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)
```

I don't have much experience in android but i have checked everywhere i could and whatever i have written seems to be working for everyone else.

**Note:** Have been testing on an actual Android10 device not AVD.

Users of the Application I am building will need to click and play videos on some posts so, Kindly suggest me if there is another/more preferred way to play videos since all i could find was this.

Comment: Your url not secured.. try https videos if it's working include network config in your manifest.

Above android 7 you need network config

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

Comment: what network configuration do you suggest?

Comment: Also, what would make it look for mms and email permissions since while trying to make my app work, it was showing in logat that these permission are not given after showing the same error,tho its not showing after since i created a new project which seems to be running https's links fine

Comment: Check the blog or in your manifest add it.  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" application tag itself

Comment: Both links are secured: 1. https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4 and 2. https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20201217192146/Screenrecorder-2020-12-17-19-17-36-828.mp4?_=1 ; Latter works fine but former doesn't. Kindly explain the difference in two.

Comment: Unsecure url not allowed

Comment: @GobuCSG, this secured link works [link](https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20201217192146/Screenrecorder-2020-12-17-19-17-36-828.mp4?_=1) but this one doesn't [link](https://samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp4/sample-5s.mp4) ; Please point out the difference and what should be done

Comment: May be video issues

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same issue in Pixel 3a and solved it by adding
[`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic) to my AndroidManifest.xml application tag.

Hope this works for you too